# SAML NameId Policy

Tags: saml

I am new to the concept of Single Sign On(SSO). I came to know that SAML request and response is the best way to achieve SSO process. I then started reading about SAML2.0. I came around a term **NameIdPolicy** in saml2.0 which was not there in saml1.0. 
Definitions say that It is the format of the NameID we request from the IdP.I want to know what is that format is? I mean what data from IDP should come in the format NameIDPolicy specify? Can anyone brief me on this NameIdPolicy concept?

Answer (score 21):

From the [SAML 2.0 core spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf), the **NameIDPolicy**

*Specifies constraints on the name identifier to be used to represent the requested subject. If omitted,
then any type of identifier supported by the identity provider for the requested subject can be used,
constrained by any relevant deployment-specific policies, with respect to privacy, for example.*

When performing identity federation, the affiliated parties must agree upon an identifier for the principal's linked accounts. The identifier string is called a **NameID** and its specification, including format, is the **NameIDPolicy**.

For example, a Service Provider (SP) initiates federation by sending an AuthnRequest to the Identity Provider (IDP) containing

```
<samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" />
```

This tells the IDP that its response Assertion XML should contain something like

```
<saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">user@example.com</saml:NameID>
```

where the email address represents the subject being authenticated.

You can learn more by reading [SAML 2.0 Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0) (well-written), the [SAML 2.0 core spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf) and the [SAML 2.0 Name Identifier document](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/4587/).